# React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy haciendo una landing y para los distintas secciones de la app las creo en distintos componentes, lo cuales hago una composicion de componentes en el app.js principal. todo marcha bien pero en cards.js me da un error.

```
Failed to compile

./src/component/cards.js
 Line 13:  Parsing error: Unterminated JSX contents

  11 |                     <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary">Go    somewhere</a>
  12 |                 </div>
> 13 |             </div>      
     |                   ^
  14 |         );
  15 |     }
  16 | }
```

Esto surge ya que en el componente cards.js (que se exporta el componente principal) tengo el siguiente codigo.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Card extends React.Component {
render() {
    return(
        <div className="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img className="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
            <div className="card-body">
                <h5 className="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p className="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>      
    );
  }
}

export default Card;
```

Nose si estoy haciendo buena practica dividir cada parte de mi app en distintos componentes y todos ellos llamarlos en un componente principal. ojala me puedan aconsejar!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tres cosas, la primera, cuando exportas `React, {Component}` puedes ahorrarte la definicion de la clase de ésta forma:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Card extends Component {
```

Y no olvides que en JSX es obligatorio el cierre de todas las etiquetas, aún así en HTML no existía conflicto con ello:

#### Erroneo:

```
<img src="x">
```

#### Correcto:

```
<img src="x" />
```

## Uso correcto de estilos con `style`

En JSX la forma correcta de asignar estilos a un elemento en linea es:

```
<div className="card" style={{
    width: "18rem"
}}>
```

Por lo que esto dejaría a tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Card extends Component {
render() {
    return(
        <div className="card" style={{width: "18rem"}}>
            <img className="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap" />
            <div className="card-body">
                <h5 className="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p className="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>      
    );
  }
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: Vale amigo, una pregunta es buena practica dividir mi landing en componentes?

Comment: Si sabes que tu landing page puede crecer o llegase a ser necesario implementar más componentes, es buena idea para facilitar un poco la parte escalable.

Answer (score 1):

cierra la imagen con `/` al final

```
<img className="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap" />
```